# Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '__asyncLoader') Vuetify 3 v-select

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vuejs3, vuetify.js, vuetifyjs3

I'm using vue 3 with vuetify 3.1.2, I have the following code :

```
<template><v-select  :items="categories"></v-select></template>
```

And here is my `onMounted` method :

```
const categories = ref<Categorie[]>([]);
onMounted(() => {
    categoriesService.getAllCategories().then((r) => {
        categories.value = r;
    }).catch(() => {
        eventBus.emit("open-popup",  {
            color:"red",
            text:"Error"
        })
    })
})
```

I would like my v-select to show "[object Object]" but everything is empty and I get these warnings :

```
Unhandled error during execution of scheduler flush. This is likely a Vue internals bug.
[Vue warn]: Invalid VNode type: undefined (undefined)
```

and this error :

```
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '__asyncLoader')
    at isAsyncWrapper (runtime-core.esm-bundler.js?d2dd:2272:1)
```

How can I resolve this?